# Scipy.cluster kmeans2

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to apply the **kmeans2 algorithm in Scipy**. The following code applies the algorithm correctly.

```
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans2,vq
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("123.csv")

km,_ = kmeans2(X,2)
idx,_ = vq(X,km)
```

How would I observe the cluster centers? I have tried print(centers), print(centroids) etc but nothing works.

How would I observe the cluster labels? For example, in the sklearn KMeans this is given by **labels_**.

I have tried print(labels) and all variations of it, which I found on the Scipy Reference Guide, but none seem to work.

Also, under the initialization methods, it states that a matrix is an available method within minit. I cannot get minit to recognise any matrices I put in. 
I usually either get an error message saying "data type not understood" or "unhashable type: 'list'.

The reason I am trying to do this is because I want to run a KMeans Clustering Algorithm where I can manually select each cluster center and then categorize each point to the closest center.

Am I just not understanding how "minit" works, or am I simply just not inputting my matrix in the right form

Comment: Could you show some data? How does `km` look like?

Answer (score 0):

km should contain the cluster centers. Try

> print(km)

As for the labels, that should be the second variable returned by kmeans2.

Here is a working example:

```
df = [[1.,2.,3.], [7.,8.,9.], [2.,2.,2.], [7.,8.,6.]]

centers,labels = kmeans2(df,2) 
print(centers) 
print(labels)
```

The result:

```
[[1.5 2.  2.5]
 [7.  8.  7.5]]
[0 1 0 1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works. However, every time I run this algorithm the clustering is different (and hence the cluster centers).  How can I tell which clustering is the most optimal, or would I need to put a really high number for the number of iterations?

Comment: KMeans places the initial cluster centers randomly, therefore it is acceptable that you do not get the same result. From multiple runs you could compute the error measurement as the mean square distance of each point to its cluster centroid. The clustering result that minimizes this error is the best. sklearn.cluster.kmeans does that automatically via its n_init parameter that is set to 10 and it provides the best result out of 10: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Comment: @CatalinStoean one way to get the same results each time is to set an initial seed value just before the kmeans code. I dont know how its done in python but in R programming, it can be coded as `>set.seed(2018) kmeans(c(1:10))`

Comment: @nemo good point. But you do not necessarily get the best solution out of several possible. Anyway, in order to do that in python, this should be fine: > from numpy import random
>random.seed(5)

Comment: @CatalinStoean careful on term usage, "best solution" and "same results (or solution)" are two different concepts. To be clear, my suggestion was for obtaining the "same results".